# Intel Wifi 8260 not working

Tags: wifi, intel

I just install Elementary Loki on my new PC.
I install the additional driver and I got an option for an proprietary module for my intel micro controller. I install it and reboot.

Ethernet is working well, but when I try to enable the wifi, the switch goes off right after.

My system is up to date :

`uname -r`
`4.4 ...`

Any idea ?

Comment: [Similar Freya issue](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/6951/5565). Perhaps it wasn't fixed in 4.4?

Comment: You can check the answer here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8492/6398

Comment: Yes thank you. The answer wasn't on this post yep when I wrote mine. It's work now